# how to change default page index.php to url

Tags: php, .htaccess

i have my `.htaccess` file here..

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /faith/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?uri=$1 [QSA,L]
```

RewriteBase /faith/    is the main folder on my local... but my problem is when i upload it in the cpanel i dont have any idea on how to use the url as my index.php .. i tried to search for it and it says that i need to change the rewritebase in a url.. but that doesn't seems to work cause what i want is my index.php will be a url.

my login page is index.php

and i want it to become sample.com so whenever i search it the only thing that i need to do is to type sample.com

Answer (score 0):

your script seems ok in .htaccess file, you just need to use the redirection file name just like you are using index.php , you can use sample.php overthere.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /faith/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ sample.php?uri=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to include some explanation.  Code-only answers do very little to educate future SO readers.  Your answer is in the moderation queue for being low-quality.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line at top of your .htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

This will load `index.php` by default when you visit `http://example.com`

Comment: You just need to add this line before `RewriteEngine On` in your code.

Comment: what happen is when i upload it on my cpanel the folders inside `faith` is the one that i upload to my public_html... so what will i write to my rewritebase then??.

Comment: You already have a .htaccess shown in question. That should be placed as `faith/.htaccess` on your website. In the same file add this line at top of your  file and test with `http://example.com/faith/`